# Fix first four numbers in textbox PHP

Tags: php, forms, textbox

I want to restrict first four number in textbox in PHP, Here's my sample code:

```
<label>Number </label>
<input name="phone" type="text" class="required" id="phone" value="<?=$phone_number?>" maxlength="11" />
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: what do you mean by restrict? You want them to be filled in? You want that users cannot change the first four numbers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to restrict a field to take only 4 numeric characters as input?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790605/how-to-restrict-a-field-to-take-only-4-numeric-characters-as-input)

Comment: Hi snicksie, Yes I want user cannot change first four fields of text box, rest 7 numbers they have to enter.

Comment: Likely this will need JS/server side validation - the user will be able to modify any value you preset in a form input. You could possibly use two inputs and disable one of them; but if they can't change it; why not just display the 4 numbers as text/a label and just prefix the number server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this...

```
$phone_number = '0116' . $_POST['phonenumber'];
```

This can be the same

```
<label>Number </label>
<input name="phone" type="text" class="required" id="phone" value="?=$phone_number?>" maxlength="11" />
```

Whereever you use the phone number add the digits you want via php.

Comment: this number field is going to next php page, should i include like that?

Comment: Yes. Just use $phone_number whenever you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<label>Number </label>
<input name="phone" type="text" class="required" id="phone" value="1234<?=$phone_number?>" maxlength="11" />
```